# VS2015 breakpoint intellisense doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

One of the new features of VS2015 (when using C#) is the new breakpoint editor that allows you to modify breakpoint conditions or messages.  The fields also come enabled with intellisense.  Except for me, it seems.  Try as I might I can't seem to get any sort of intellisense to appear when messing with breakpoints.

A coworker also has 2015 installed and the intellisense works fine for them.  I've compared the Visual Studio info between the two of us and I can't seem to find anything that would explain the difference.  Any extension I have installed he also has.

Is there some setting somewhere that I need to enable to get the breakpoint intellisense?  Are there any extensions that may interfere with this feature?

For reference here's the VS2015 info from the about screen:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
>   Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
>   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.6.01055
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00325-60003-45120-AA615
>   Microsoft Visual Basic 2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00325-60003-45120-AA615
>   Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00325-60003-45120-AA615
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio   2.6.12735.14
>   AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.6.12735.14 
>   * Ankh.Package 2.6.12735.14
>   * Subversion 1.9.2 via SharpSvn 1.9002.3777.76
>
> SharpSvn is linked to: Apr 1.5.1, Apr-util 1.5.4, Cyrus Sasl 2.1.26, eXpat 2.1.0, LibSSH2 1.6.0, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015, Serf 1.3.8, SQLite 3.8.11.1, Subversion 1.9.2-SharpSvn, Utf8proc 1.1.5, ZLib 1.2.8
>   SharpSvn is optionally linked to: Berkeley DB 4.4.20, SharpPlink 0.65.0(SharpSvn)
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0
>   ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
>   For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
>   For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.5
>   Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2   Build 104.0.20151218.120627
>   JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2015 JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
>   Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.3.0
>   NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
>   Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
>   Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   1.7.4.0
>   TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Same problem for me. And others: also asked [here on superUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1026798/intellisense-in-breakpoint-condition-window-does-not-work#) without answer yet

Comment: As multiple people seem to have this issue there might be a corrupted IntelliSense package around.. But I guess you've installed VS15 from the same source as your co-worker, so this shouldn't be the problem.. Have a look at this post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried these 10 solution proposals?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1

EDIT: 1st solution of the link above solved Kyle's problem.

Here's the fix retrieved from the link above:

> Solution 1:
>
> Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor-> All Languages->General
>
> Enable "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information"
>
> [image]

Hope this helps

Comment: The first solution on that list resolved the issue.  Perhaps edit that one into the post.